# Remote Database is connecting

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel to build a project it was working then my server went offline(i am using another workstation just for database and other purposes)after the workstation  restart then I couldn't login into my site it throws this error

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

my env file

```
 APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=ipaddress
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ssweb
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=300
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: One reason this may happen is because a firewall is blocking the response from the server.
Another reason is that the host name is incorrect.
This could also mean there is a (temporary) problem with the server

Comment: My friends using the same server and they have another project and they can access the db but not mine @Alihosseinshahabi

Comment: Restart mysql or the entire server and try again? Else it's probably a firewall. Also note to be careful with posting your environment parameters. You seem to have removed the really important ones, but please generate a new app key when deploying this project ;)

Comment: i Will check it Thanks for the advice @Loek

Answer (score 0):

It means you cant connect to the server. Check your connecting to the correct ip address and your firewall is configured to allow traffic.